# How to make multiple clients with SimpleTcp?

Tags: c#, wpf, tcpclient, ethernet

I have a connection with TCP / IP. I want a multiple connection. I'm using SimpleTcp. It is very simple and useful for single connection. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make multiple connections with SimpleTcp.

The code below is the one used for single connection.

```
public void EthernetConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            string IpAddress = Ip.Text;
            int Port = Convert.ToInt32(PortName.Text);
            SimpleTcpClient client = new SimpleTcpClient(IpAddress, Port, false, null, null);
            if (!client.IsConnected)
            {

                client.Connect();
                if (client != null)
                {
                    if (client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                        client.Events.DataReceived += EthernetDataReceived;
                        client.Events.Connected += EthernetConnected;
                        client.Events.Disconnected += EthernetDisconnected;
                        timer.Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not Connected");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                client.Events.DataReceived -= EthernetDataReceived;
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

EthernetDataReceived

```
private void EthernetDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedFromServerEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var Data = e.Data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

How can the EthernetDataReceived function in single connection be used in multiple connections? Creating a separate function for each link sounds ridiculous.

I can use different structures other than SimpleTcp. But I'm a beginner please help?

Comment: All of you clients can subscribe to the same function. client.Events.DataReceived += EthernetDataReceived;

Comment: Isn't there a problem if data comes from all of them at the same time?

Comment: Also, how do I know which server data is coming from?

Comment: sender argument will be the client that recieved the data.
you can add a lock for mutual exclusion.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you mean. Please, can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EthernetDataReceived` is just an event handler that can be used to handle the `DataReceived` event from any `SimpleTcpClient` object. You can think of it as a method that may be called by any object from any thread.

> Isn't there a problem if data comes from all of them at the same time?

Then the method will be called once per event that gets raised. This isn't an issue as long as you don't read or modify any shared data in the event handler. If you do this, you need to make the method thread-safe which is a topic of its own.

> Also, how do I know which server data is coming from?

You should be able to cast the `sender` argument and check the properties of the `SimpleTcpClient`:

```
private void EthernetDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedFromServerEventArgs e)
{
    SimpleTcpClient client = (SimpleTcpClient)sender;
    //...

}
```

Or check the `DataReceivedFromServerEventArgs` whatever that is.

Comment: Thank you so much. This way I can access the object. But I cannot access the properties of the object. How can I access the client's features such as ip address, port, etc.

Comment: IP address appears to be non-public data and I don't know how to access it.

Comment: I need to connect to more than 10 servers, put the data from them into a process and then write them in a separate list. Yes I can access the client object but how can I use it as distinctive.

Comment: I don't know what `SimpleTcpClient ` is but if it doesn't expose the IP address using a public member, you need to use reflection to retrieve it. Or use separate event handlers.